# Populating Oracle ADF tables

Tags: oracle-adf

The question is about ADF tables. When we have the data coming from the database it populates the table kind of automatically. That's easy! But, let's say we are importing data from the XML file. What is the best way to populate data to the tables now?

I've tried it doing like saving all the data to the list of classes and then getting the values into the table. But in this way, you have to enter the list index to every field manually. It's kind of too much work. How to automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

That's two steps:

1. populate xml into java object (I assume you know this part)
2. Then create a class with a method to return the List;
   publish the class as Data Control, so you can bind the method to an ADF UI Table